# Secure non-repeating Random alphanumeric URL slug

Tags: java, security, cryptography, slug

I'm able to achieve **non-repeating Random alphanumeric URL slug** part with Base58, something like this,

```
private static final char[] BASE58_CHARS = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
private static final int LENGTH = BASE58_CHARS.length;
public static String genSlug(long priimaryKeyId) {
    char[] buffer = new char[20];
    int index = 0;
    do {
        int i = (int) (priimaryKeyId % LENGTH);
        buffer[index++] = BASE58_CHARS[i];
        priimaryKeyId = priimaryKeyId / LENGTH;
    } while (priimaryKeyId > 0);
    return new String(buffer, 0, index);
}
```

But how to achieve **secure-randomness** with it?

If we do

```
Hashing.sha256().hashString(genSlug(priimaryKeyId), StandardCharsets.UTF_8).toString();
```

the slug becomes 64 characters , that's too long (expecting it to be the same length as the genSlug, which is between 1 and 12 chars long)..

Comment: @Artjom, updated the question, 13+ chars is too long

Answer (score 1):

You could certainly truncate the output of the hash function and it would still appear random, but the possibility of a hash collision will rise. Since your constraint is a maximum output of 12 characters, this means that you have to truncate the hash output to 70 *bits* (`12/8 * log(256)/log(58)`). Due to the birthday paradox, it is likely that you get a collision after 2<sup>70/2</sup> such hashes.

Since you need guaranteed uniqueness, you can use a pseudo-random permutation (PRP) to transform `priimaryKeyId` into a random token. A block cipher is such a PRP. Since the maximum size of the block size is 70, you can safely use Triple DES for this use case. It has a block size of 64 bit which is also the size of a `long`.

Example (not thoroughly tested):

```
private static final char[] BASE58_CHARS = "123456789ABCDEFGHJKLMNPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz".toCharArray();
private static final int LENGTH = BASE58_CHARS.length;
private static final BigInteger LENGTH_BI = BigInteger.valueOf(LENGTH);

// TODO: CHANGE THE KEY TO SOMETHING RANDOM!
private static final byte[] KEY = new byte {1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8};

public static String genSlug(long priimaryKeyId) {
    ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(8);
    bb.putLong(priimaryKeyId);

    Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("DESede/ECB/NoPadding");
    cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(KEY, "DESede"));
    byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(bb.array());
    BigInteger bi = new BigInteger(1, encrypted);

    char[] buffer = new char[20];
    int index = 0;
    do {
        BigInteger i = bi.mod(LENGTH_BI);
        buffer[index++] = BASE58_CHARS[i.intValue()];
        bi = bi.divide(LENGTH_BI);
    } while (bi.compareTo(BigInteger.ZERO) == 1);
    return new String(buffer, 0, index);
}
```

The main thing you need to do is to keep the key safe.

Comment: It might be a little picky, but please do not recommend TripleDES as default anymore – even if it would probably be suitable for this use-case, there are normally no reasons to use it but a lot of reasons against it (security, inferior performance, ...)

Comment: @K.Biermann You are correct in that DES or Triple DES should not be used for encryption these days. The use case here is different though, because a 64 bit block cipher was needed. Since Triple DES provides 112 bit of security, it is still not that bad. Other block ciphers include Blowfish, Speck, Hasty Pudding, etc.